# what's the dll should I use in Json.net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, json.net

I downloaded JSON.NET library and installed (ran command `Build\runbuild.cmd`) it create two directories inside `Working` folder. Inside this directories there's a lot of direcotories each one with a `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` dll I don't know what to use. What's the dll should I use to use in my C# program to run under windows 7 and 8 (and 8.1)?

Comment: When you build your project, the Json.net dll should be in the same folder as your created exe.

Comment: If you are trying to include json.net in your project to begin with, use nuget instead, which will install the references and dlls for you.

Comment: Ideally you should be using an IDE such as visual studio and NuGet as a package manager, which will appropriately place DLLS and include references based on the target framework your application is being built against.

Comment: @gunr2171: There's no one. As I mentioned I built it using a  JSON.NET's script not VS. I've never used nuget (I don't do much .NET) I will try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on your project and "Manage NuGet Packages..."

[image: Right click menu]

from there you can search for json.net and install the package from there.

[image: Search and Install]

Comment: If im not mistaken, this will also notify you of updates to the packages. These alerts I think show up in the top right of visual studios 2013. look for the flag.